# Explode animated object

Tags: animation

I am new to Blender.  I have a Mixamo model with a blended animation of the model running and getting shot and flying backwards.

What I'm trying to do is fracture the model at the point of impact and shatter as it fly backwards.  I love it to fracture into cubes and they could bounce on a plane.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Explode effect to cause your object to fracture at the selected frame.

Find this in the menu:: Object :: Quick Effects :: Explode, which uses the Fracture and Particle System modifiers.  Also check out the settings for begin and end frame to the particle emissions that you'd set to your "point of impact".

[image]

and for the particle system Rendering, use the Cube object (with appropriate settings on scale)

[image]

I include my example: [image]